# Shared file in Angular2 from one Location

Tags: angular

We are developing Angular2.0 application, where we have a shared(static) file, which contains all application related constants.

Now when we have to get any of these constants in any component, we have to first import that file.

Now the challenge is if we have 25+ component, we have to write import on every component.

Do we have a centralized place in Angular 2.0 +, where we can write down this import statement and this will accessible in whole application?

Comment: It's obvious. If you do not describe something in a file then you have to import it.

Comment: @Damask , aggred  but my point if you have to use a file application level , so instead importing on every file better import in a place and use every where.

Comment: So this is NG2 then you are likely to use typescript. And the thing is that it is compilable. If you do not want to pull it as a TS dependency then you can work it around by creation a JS file that will be put in index.html directly. Then you can try to use it in your component by looking at the global context like window['globalSetting']. But this does not bring the consistency into your code. And in case of some probable refactoring in future you might get issues.

Comment: Agreed, this is a workaround , I am looking some permanent fix